# Limit service to a specific LAN on a Linux machine connecting two LANs?

Tags: linux, networking, router, lan

I have a hypothetical question regarding how networking stack works on Linux. If I have a machine with two NICs, sitting on different LANs. Something like this:

- NIC A on LAN A, 192.168.1.3/24
- NIC B on LAN B, 192.168.2.5/24

Now if I have a web service on 192.168.2.5:80, intended to serve only LAN B's hosts, how do I prevent LAN's A's hosts to access it?

My understanding is that, if I don't add anything to netfilter/iptables/nftables, a default linux kernel will pass requests sent to NIC B's IP address from NIC A's neighbours (LAN A). And the box will work like a router, by default. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My understanding is that, if I don't add anything to netfilter/iptables/nftables, a default linux kernel will pass requests sent to NIC B's IP address from NIC A's neighbours (LAN A). And the box will work like a router, by default. Is that correct?

Almost. Forwarding between LAN segments can be enabled or disabled in the kernel. You can check `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward` to see if it is enabled for IPv4 (and you can set it by writing `0` or `1` into this pseudo-file).

Additionally, what many people forget is that routing must work for **all** participants. E.g. machines in LAN A will need to know that for IP addresses in LAN B, the packets first will need to go to 192.168.1.3 to reach you machine with two NICs. If 192.168.1.3 is the **gateway** (default route) for all machines on LAN A, then this happens automatically. If not, machines in LAN A need additional routing information (which for example can be distributed by DHCP).

Also, **iptables is not routing**. Too many people read tutorials that use `iptables` for routing, and then confuse the two. `iptables` is for **filtering** (i.e., a firewall). You can route without having `iptables` compiled into the kernel, at all.

So, in your scenario: If you want to keep hosts in LAN A ignorant of hosts in LAN B (and vice versa), just disable routing on the machine with two NICs. If they should be able to see each other in principle, except for the web service on 192.168.2.5:80, **then** you need filtering rules on top of routing to exclude exactly this web service.

And the whole scenario can get more complicated depending on how LAN A and LAN B are supposed to access "the internet".

(General advice: If you want to ask anything about networking, **first draw a network diagram** with all the important parts).

---

> A typical home router has a web login open to LAN (LAN B in the original question), and I guess by default this login is not accessible via WAN (LAN A).

In this case, the router is already set up differently: The LAN side uses a private address IP range, and those IPs are not supposed to appear on the WAN side (because there are multiple private LANs connected to this WAN, which all could use the same addresses). So the router does network address translation (NAT): For every incoming request from LAN A addressed to WAN, this request will get entered into a table (connection tracking), and all outgoing and incoming packets for that request will be modified, replacing the IP address (and port) in LAN a with the IP address the router has on WAN (and a randomly chosen port for this connection).

This alone prevents anything in WAN from initiating connections to anything in LAN A, including the interface of the router in LAN A.

On top of that, you have firewall rules preventing anything incoming from WAN to be routed to LAN A, except for those connections that originated in LAN A.

And if you want to allow this, you need to setup "port forwarding".

> In this case, what mechanism prevents WAN to login?

So in the above scenario, the login server just binds only on the IP address in LAN A.

> I think by default Linux should allow the access, (and ip_forward is an irrelevant option for this specific case) so it should be some firewall rules that forbids it, is that correct?

In principle, yes, but see the details described above (NAT on top of firewall rules).

Comment: thanks! In this case, the packet received from interface A is addressed to the IP address bound to interface B, hence tagged RTN_LOCAL, should it be controlled by ip_forward flag? the kernel function dn_route_input_slow seems to suggest not.

Comment: "In this case, the packet received from interface A is addressed to the IP address bound to interface B," Then it's addressed to the "machine with two NICs", and will be processed by it. If this packet was supposed to go from some machine in LAN A to some other machine in LAN B, it should be addressed to the IP address of the machine in LAN B.

Comment: And the only way to stop this packet, from other machiens on LAN A, addressed to interface B, would be using firewall rules, by iptables/nftables ?

Comment: If your question is "how can I stop a packet addressed to a local interface that is **not** the interface of the interface in the LAN segment where this packet comes from", then yes, by default, Linux processes all incoming packets locally that match *any* of the local IP addresses. You could use firewall rules to prevent this, or you could have your application bind only on particular IP addresses instead of all IP addresses. The real question now is **why** you'd want to do that, because what Linux does is the correct behaviour.

Comment: So the whole thing starts to look like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - your Y is "I want to stop a packet to a local IP different from the attached IP" (and you should update your question to reflect this problem, because it's not any longer about routing from LAN A to LAN B), but what is your X? And likely your X can be achieved in a better way.

Comment: Here is an example that I can think of. A typical home router has a web login open to LAN (LAN B in the original question), and I guess by default this login is not accessible via WAN (LAN A). In this case, what mechanism prevents WAN to login? I think by default Linux should allow the access, (and ip_forward is an irrelevant option for this specific case) so it should be some firewall rules that forbids it, is that correct?